# HTTPs URL encryption

Tags: encryption, ssl, https, cryptography, ssl-certificate

when we use https.........for example to send login credentials(https://example.com?username=aaaa&password=aaaa123). HTTPS encrypts the data using SSL certificate. So the url will be encrypted string. I am giving two requests with the same url(https://example.com?username=aaaa&password=aaaa123). On every request the url will be encrypted. Will the encrypted url of the first request be same as the encrypted url of the second request? Is the SSL certificate going to be different everytime btween client and server?

Thanks,
Iqbal

Comment: what do you need ? if you need then different than you can add ?rand=*random-number* parameter.

And what is "encrypted URL" ? for what i understand, TLS creates encrypted tunnel, and then all the traffic gets encrypted. Fro moutside you would not even able to determine reliably where the url started. All the HTTP traffic would get encrypted, all headers, all commands, etc. You would not even see "GET " before URL.
BTW, why not use standard https : // name:password@server/path URI format?

Comment: Note that HTTPS doesn't encrypt the data using the certificate, but using keys negotiated using the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the encrypted url of the first request be same as the encrypted url of the second request?

The URL will be the same, because you said so. If you're asking whether the *encryption* of the URL will be different, the question is meaningless. It's impossible for anyone to tell, because the entire request is encrypted, so it is impossible to pick out the part that consists of the encrypted URL.

> Is the SSL certificate going to be different everytime btween client and server?

The SSL certificate is the same for the entire SSL session, which persists beyond the current connection for as long as both client and server remember it.